# What's the best way to test the time based aspects of your smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, testing, unittesting

I have some functions in my contracts that activate x days after the contract starts, or x days after the contract enters a given state. Are there any best practices (or just practices :P) to test this? I'm using truffle as my framework.

Comment: I accidentally voted to leave this open, but both suggestions for duplication above are great and this should be closed.